# Extend app background image to Navigation Bar and Status Bar

Tags: ios, cocoa-touch, ios7

I am trying to get an effect like this:
http://dribbble.com/shots/1473643-Fashion-app/attachments/219674

Basically I would like to extend the app background image to the Navigation Bar and the Status Bar.

Any ideas how to do this.

Answer (score 1):

The following lines of code inside viewDidLoad of your vc will help you to have a similar effect:

```
self.navigationController.navigationBar.barStyle = UIBarStyleBlack;    
[self.navigationController.navigationBar setBackgroundImage:[UIImage new] forBarMetrics:UIBarMetricsDefault];
self.navigationController.navigationBar.shadowImage = [UIImage new];
self.navigationController.navigationBar.translucent = YES;
[self.navigationController.navigationBar setTitleTextAttributes:@{NSForegroundColorAttributeName : [UIColor whiteColor]}];
self.navigationController.navigationBar.backgroundColor = [[UIColor blackColor] colorWithAlphaComponent:0.3];
```